# I killed my Tiva C-Series LaunchPad. Can anyone rescue it?

Tags: microcontroller

I have a **Texas Instruments Tiva C-Series LaunchPad (Part Number: EK-TM4C123GXL)**. I've got the LaunchPad for **only a month**. Most recently, I used **Energia** to upload the following code into my LaunchPad:

https://gist.github.com/phil3c7r0n/4e22cd686ae196f92e6b

In my code, I used the following pins: PB_7, PE_5, **PB_6**, **PB_4**, PE_0, **PD_0**, PD_2

And here is the **guideline** of the LaunchPad:

[image]
[image]

As you see, in my code I wanted to use PB_7, PE_5, PB_6, PB_4 as OUTPUT with Pulse Width Modulator (~PWM). However, for a stupid reason that I forgot about the guideline included in the LaunchPad's box, **I messed them all up: I used Analog pins for Digital-purposed pins and Digital pins for Analog-purposed pins.**

**Importantly and deadly**, I used **PB_4**, which has main functionality as "**SPI CLK**" (according to the guideline), for **~PWM** (!!!). I also did the same thing with **PB_6** and **PD_0**, which both have functionality as "**SPI MISO**" (according to the guideline).

**Now my LaunchPad is dead now**, and this is exactly how it looks:

[image]

Let me describe it: A steady half-green-and-yellow light indicating the power on, and that's all. I strongly want you to know that I **PLUGGED** the LaunchPad in my computer and it did **NOT CONNECT** to the computer **AT ALL**:

1. The computer didn't play the sound as usual when it detected USB connection.
2. There is no driver appeared in Device Manager although I had already viewed all hidden Devices:

[image]

There should be Stellaris Virtual COM Port located inside Ports, and there should be Stellaris In-Circuit Debug Interface (ICDI) driver as well. They disappeared, all of them.

3. From 1 and 2, I'm pretty sure that there is no way to erase and reset the factory settings for the LaunchPad.
4. I had already used LMFlashProgrammer from TI:

[image]

5. I had already used other USB ports on my computer.
6. I had already used other computers.
7. I had already tried to press the Reset button, even SW1 and SW2, but nothing happened.
8. Please don't tell me to upload the blink example (or any code) to the LaunchPad. I had told you, the computer didn't recognize the LaunchPad AT ALL.

*[Editted] My schematic:*

[image]

**IMAGINATIVELY, IT WAS LIKE I LEFT THE KEY IN THE ROOM AND LOCKED THE DOOR.**

**Please help me with this problem! I feel frustrating now, and I need the LaunchPad back. I'm in an online course and it is in session!
SINCERELY THANKS!**

Comment: I guarantee that I check my question every day until I solve the problem. All contributive comments are appreciated. Suggested answers are extremely good as well, and I will mark suggested answer a check if I solve it (of course).

Comment: R9 and R10 connect PD0&PB6 and PD1&PB&, respectively. Be aware that the jumpers must be desoldered and removed if you want to use either of these pairs of pins. I've heard that the board can be damaged if both of these are used as outputs simultaneously.

Comment: To be clear, have you disconnected the board from any circuitry?

Comment: @phil3c7r0n - To reduce the chances of other readers duplicating effort from your previous question about the same problem, here is a link to it for other people to read: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/222331/i-cannot-do-anything-with-my-tiva-c-series-launchpad : Since your code mentions driving motors for a robot, there are ways you could have caused hardware damage to your LaunchPad board e.g. if there was insufficient reverse voltage clamping etc. - you didn't supply a schematic for readers to be able to consider that possibility. I suggest ordering a new board :-( Good luck

Comment: Realistically you have two options. One involves a sacrifice, at midnight on the night of a full moon, in a forest clearing, the other involves $12.99 and the Texas Instrument website. I will not comment on the respective merits of either.

Comment: Shame I didn't see this yesterday. TI had pi (3.14) shipping yesterday. Maybe today still too.

Comment: Here is the data sheet, http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tm4c123gh6pm.pdf it would be your best resource for resolving this issue.  And here are the schematics http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spmu296/spmu296.pdf Which shows the PB_4 and PB_6 are just GPIO on U1-A on Sheet 1 of the schematics. 4.3.4.3 in user manual has a reset procedure. And.... I have already wasted $12.99 of everyone's time.

Comment: Everybody, Thank you for your great job. I decided to buy a new LaunchPad, and I have already ordered it. Again, sincerely thanks for all!

Comment: Remember to desolder R9 and R10 before use, so that the I/O ports can be used independently (without damaging the board).

Answer (score 1):

I, too, once destroyed my Tiva C-series dev board.  Maybe the high inductance of motors drew current even when the output stage of the uC pins tried to protect itself.  I can't see what is wrong in the picture of the board you posted. You can spend hours debugging this, and perhaps someone knows exactly what you did.  However, the board is $25 and ships next day from digikey.